# PHP for each e-mail in array, send unique key from another array

Tags: php, arrays, email

I'm more of a front-end dev and I'm not very far with PHP. I mostly use jquery and reactjs for my applications. I'm creative when it comes to design, but I got barely any inspiration while writing something functional. I need a way to send for each unique e-mail from an array, a random key from another array to that email, but so that each email get's an unique key.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't sound difficult. Try something like this.

```
$emails = ["first@example.com", "second@example.com"];

$uniqueEmails = array_unique($emails);
$uniqueKeys = ["uniq1", "uniq2"];

foreach ($uniqueEmails as $key => $email) {

    //TODO: sendMail($email, $key);

}
```

The [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function is used to remove duplicates from your array.

As far as I understand your question, you want to send the unique key to that email address. The PHP mail function can do that for you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure that every array element is unique (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
2. Do foreach with this array && on every iterate do the following (**Take random key from second array by index && unset it (to avoid duplicate)**) && send email